# How to avoid the undefined errors in Vue projects when you empty Vuex objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Example. I have a `user` Vuex data that I use like this in templates:

```
// Inside <template>
<button
  v-if="!user.expiredInfo.isExpired"
</button>

// Inside <script>
data () {
 return {
   disable: this.user.expiredInfo.isExpired ? 'text-muted' : '',
 }
}
```

I have an action that does this:

```
const state = {
  user: {}
}

async logout ({ commit }) {
  commit('SET_USER', {})
},
```

So there's an error when I logout:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'isExpired' of undefined`

How to prevent this kind of problems?

Comment: You are resetting the entire user Object to an empty object so obviously you will get undefined. If you rely on the `expiredInfo` property to be there on your object you should just empty the value that belongs to it. An alternative would be to create a computed property that does all the checking for your. This would be cleaner and a safer approach if the first is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `user` to null when there is no logged in user, instead of trying to circumvent such errors with an empty object. This means you'll always need to take into consideration the fact that the user may not actually be logged in at a certain point in the template where you would render some data from the (possibly nonexistent) user object.

You can do things like this to avoid this kind of error (depending on the logic you want):

```
<button v-if="user && !user.expiredInfo.isExpired"></button>
<button v-if="!user || !user.expiredInfo.isExpired"></button>
```

Or if you have a lot of logged-in-specific templates, something like this:

```
<template v-if="user">
  <!-- It's safe to access properties of the user object anywhere in here -->
</template>
```

Never assume that `this.user` will always be non-null (unless that is an invariant you have enforced).